# Method require() doesn't work with mapped reference image links - React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, image, mapping, require

I have data file that contains array with links to local images. When I try to map this array and render list of images then **method require() allows me to put inside only name of image file and access path separately**, like on image1 of code below.

Image2 neither image3 can't work even if image source seems to be the same as in image1 example.

Why does it work like this? Can I work around it somehow? **I don't want to correct my src attribute every time I need to render an images list**. Additional, getting images by import is not a best way because length of array can be huge and also can change dynamically as well.

**Thanks for help and greetings.**

```
   // news.image = 'news-img1.jpg',
   // news.imageSrc = '../images/news-img1.jpg'

const NewsList = ({ newsList }) => {
   const listItems = newsList.map((news) => {
      return (
         <li key={news.id}>
            <img src={require(`../images/${news.image}`)} alt={news.title} /> // image1
            <img src={require(`${news.imageSrc}`)} alt={news.titleSrc} /> // image2
            <img src={require(news.imageSrc)} alt={news.titleSrc} /> // image3
         </li>
      )
   })
   return (
      <section className="news-list">
         <ul>
            {listItems}
         </ul>
      </section>
   );
}

export default NewsList;
```

Comment: Is it possible to send an actual URL as the imageSrc? Currently, this method of importing images dynamically is definitely not an ideal approach if you are doing this for an actual website/app.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I wouldn't include my images inside the `src` folder of the project and instead put them in a `public/images` folder for example. This way, no `require` statements would be needed, as React will copy the images directly, without any modifications to names or paths.

Example code:

```
   // news.image = 'news-img1.jpg',
   // news.imageSrc = '../images/news-img1.jpg'

const NewsList = ({ newsList }) => {
   const listItems = newsList.map((news) => {
      return (
         <li key={news.id}>
            <img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/${news.image}`} alt={news.title} /> // image1
         </li>
      )
   })
   return (
      <section className="news-list">
         <ul>
            {listItems}
         </ul>
      </section>
   );
}

export default NewsList;
```

Comment: But when you not importing method, webpack will not build those images..